# Import MySQL file into Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, import

I have tried to find an answer for this elsewhere but cannot, I hope someone can help me.

I am trying to import the MySQL sample database into Oracle SQL Developer.

I have an existing database/connection I want to dump it into. I have created an empty table named classicmodels in my existing connection. Yes that name is only 1 table within the sample db, correct. Ignore the error in naming convention.

When I R-click on it and try 'import data' I cannot import a .sql file, I can only do it with XL, CSV, etc.

When I try and run a script it found on dba.stackexchange
@\path\mysqlsampledatabase.sql , I get a series of 'please provide substitution value' messages, which does not make sense to me given that I am importing a database which is built for SQL (ie what reason is there to substitute).

Pictures below:

[image: The 'UnseenCollection' is a single table I imported as a csv file. I need to import the mysqlsampledatabase file such that it shows up the same way, I can access all tables within the sample db.]

The 'UnseenCollection' is a single table I imported as a csv file. I need to import the mysqlsampledatabase file such that it shows up the same way, I can access all tables within the sample db.

Anyone can help I would appreciate it. I need the end result to be the entire mysqlsampledatabase to populate within the 'classicmodels' node.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[connect to MySQL](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-supports-db2-sybase-mysql-access-and-teradata/)

connect to Oracle

for a single MySQL table, right-click, 'Copy to Oracle'
for a few tables, select, drag and drop onto Oracle connection (requires newer version of SQL Developer)

for an entire MySQL database, [use the migration project feature](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/06/moving-data-to-oracle-with-migration-workbench/)

[image]

Comment: I can't get nearly to the page you've posted. I got the corrct JDBC driver, I see MySQL in the Connections box, but when I try 'Choose Database' I get an error message telling me Access denied for user 'name' (using password: YES).

I have no idea what this means, or where I supplied, or didn't, a password of YES. 

The tutorials on your site look very helpful, but I am stuck somewhere much more basic than what they help with. Thanks for your post all the same.